# Strikethrough Markdown Not Working

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

Strikethrough is not working properly when rendering on the site, but works in preview. I have found 2 ways striking through in markdown (as seen [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/strikethrough-with-github-markdown)):

I belive the way the following markdown renders is buggy;

```
<del>
#question
some text

some more text
</del>
```

- `#` No longer results heading formatting
- Strikethrough in rendering on site only striked through the heading and nothing else (in preview it striked through everything, which is acceptable).

Community platform: ordinary stackoverflow (in case they have different markdown versions)

Comment: The bug is probably that it renders in preview while it shouldn't.

Comment: Stijn possible. The only thing which is absolutely for sure that it is inconsistent one way or another. The comment of "Brandon Jun 14 '13 at 4:53" and onward makes it seem like this did work at some point however.

Answer (score 56):

I've used <s>strikethrough</s> often and quite successfully. I think you might not be using the correct syntax. I use `<s>text</s>`.

If you can't see the struck out text above, then it might be a browser render problem. Here's a screenshot of what the <s>strikethrough</s> should look like;

[image: Struck through text]

Comment: I've also had success with the more verbose `<strike>Lorem ipsum</strike>` (No comment support for it)

Comment: good to know <s></s> also does this. the fact that <del> as found in my link works, but somehow does not, is still irritating though.

Comment: Does it work in comments? <strike>strike</strike> ... <del>del</del> ... <s>s</s> ... ~singletilde~ ... ~~doubletilde~~ (also see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/103691/19408 )